# iOS current time require timezone?

Tags: ios, nsdate

In the example below, will it always show the current time on the user's device wherever in the world they are or will it just show GMT and am I required to get and set the timezone?

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components =
[gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:today];

NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];

NSLog(@"hour %d", hour);
NSLog(@"minute %d", minute);
NSLog(@"second %d", second);
```

Comment: No. it's not required to convert to time zone. but it's also depends on whats your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html) Apple guide:

> By default, NSCalendar uses the default time zone for the
>   application—or process—when the calendar object is created. Unless the
>   default time zone has been otherwise set, it is the time zone set in
>   System Preferences.

So, you don't need any changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the current time of user's device, you should add the following line of code.

components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];